# How to fix a shifted grid in Flot Charts?

Tags: jquery, html, flot

I use https://github.com/flot/flot

I make chart:

```
$.plot("#chart", [data.points], {
        series: {
            label: data.title,
            lines: {
                show: true,
            },
            points: {
                show: true
            },
        },
        yaxis: {
            tickDecimals: 0,
            alignTicksWithAxis: 1
        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: "time",
            timeformat: "%d/%m/%Y",
            show: true,
            minTickSize: [1, "day"],
            min: (new Date(2016, 5, 21)).getTime(),
            max: (new Date(2016, 5, 28)).getTime(),
            alignTicksWithAxis: 1
        },
        grid: {
            borderWidth: 1,
            labelMargin:10,
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: true,
            mouseActiveRadius:15
        },
        legend:{
            container: '.flc-legend',
            backgroundOpacity: 0.5,
            noColumns: 0,
            lineWidth: 0
        }
    });
```

But grid shifted. How to fix it?

I attach screenshot to the problem:

[image: screenshot]

Data:
[[1466974800000, 10], [1466888400000, 10], [1466802000000, 10] ...]

Comment: The grid lines are at midnight, your data is not.

Comment: @Raidri what?) Could you explain me?